# Changing Ubuntu Wallpaper Using Terminal or From command Line

Tags: gnome, console, desktop-customization, ubuntu-11.10

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell and unity and I was wondering how to change the **desktop wallpaper** form **terminal** or **command** line .

I found the following but i can't seem to get it to work ,

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options/images --type list --list-type string "[file:/path/to/first.png:100,file:/path/to/second.png:100]"
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  I don't know if this is your problem, but the man page says that the key name is a parameter, not an option, so you should try putting it after the options, e.g. `gconftool-2 --set --type list --list-type string /apps "[file...]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this if I were you: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/img.jpg` (tip from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity))

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
$ gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options/images "[file:/path/to/first.png:100,file:/path/to/second.png:100]"
```

It successfully sets that key/value for me:

```
$ gconftool-2 -R /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper 
 /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0:
  /apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options:
   bg_color2 = []
   bg_image_pos = []
   bg_fill_type = []
   images = [file:/path/to/first.png:100,file:/path/to/second.png:100]
   bg_image = []
   bg_color1 = []
```